# How to integrate PAWN compiler into Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide, pawn

I want integrate **PAWN** compiler and its syntax highlighting into Eclipse... What's the recommended way to do that?

Is it possible?

Thanks.
https://compuphase.com/pawn/pawn.htm

Comment: Eclipse editors must be written specifically for Eclipse so you can't just use an existing highlighter. [Eclipse Xtext](https://eclipse.org/Xtext/) provides a system for adding new languages to Eclipse - but this is quite a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Eclipse Xtext](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) but it will take some time to get it to work.